# A question on Wolstenholme's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The classical Wolstenholme's Theorem, states that if $p>3$ is a prime number, then the numerator of the fraction
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{p-1}
$$
is divisible by $p^2$. Is it possible that the numerator is divisible by $p^3$ ? I have checked this out for the first $50$ primes $p>3$ and it seems to be that the numerator is divisible $p^2$ but not by $p^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=denominator%20of%20%28numerator%20of%20sum_%28k%20%3D%201%29%5E16842%20%201%2Fk%29%2F%2816843%29%5E3) shows that for the first [Wolstenholme prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme_prime) $p = 16843$,
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{p-1}$$
is divisible by $p^3$.

Comment: And indeed that's one way to define [Wolstenholme primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme_prime). The only ones known so far are $16843$ and $2124679$, though it is conjectured that there are infinitely many.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I suspected that, but wasn't sure. Thanks for adding!